# put link before redirect laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel

i have laravel project 5.3
i need laravel to always put something before the url 
i mean if i did this to laravel

```
Route::resource('/users','UsersController');
```

i need

```
Route::resource('something/users','UsersController');
```

for every link i have in the project 
when i move the project to appserv 
its always redirect to

```
localhost/mylink
```

and its should be like this

```
locahost/projectname/mylink
```

thanks

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-group-prefixes

Comment: what about links on views they will always redirect without project name

Comment: You need to change the links accordingly, or use the helper method `route()` to call named routes

Answer (score 0):

As [Laravel 5.3 docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#route-group-prefixes) says you can use group prefixes:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'something'], function () {
    Route::resource('users','UsersController');
});
```